# Change Oracle port from port 8080

Tags: oracle, port

How do I change Oracle from port 8080? My Eclipse is using 8080, so I can't use that.

Comment: If you connect to localhost:8080 with your browser and get a username / password login request saying `XDB`, this is likely the problem :)

Answer (score 251):

From Start | Run open a command window.
Assuming your environmental variables are set correctly start with the following:

```
C:\>sqlplus /nolog
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Aug 26 10:40:44 2008
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password: <enter password if will not be visible>
Connected.

SQL> Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(3010); [Assuming you want to have HTTP going to this port]    
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>quit
```

then open browser and use 3010 port.

Comment: +1, this worked perfectly for my Oracle XE installation (moved it from port 8080 to port 8088 using `exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(8088)`).

Comment: copied from here http://www.coderanch.com/t/81448/Oracle-OAS/change-port-number-Oracle-xe

Comment: The above solution works with Oracle Express 10g, Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Looks like DBMS_XDB is deprecated with Oracle 12c, heads up  http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xdb.htm#ARPLS371

Comment: I am getting an Access Denied error on this - Ubuntu environment

Comment: I just get this error.

``ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31050: Access denied
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 528
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 667
ORA-06512: at line 1``

Comment: With 11.2.0.2.0: `SQL> EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(0);
BEGIN DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(0); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31024: Parser initialization failed with LPX-54 error
while parsing a stream to XOB
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 516
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 645
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Comment: getting error ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31024: Parser initialization failed with LPX-54 error
while parsing a stream to XOB
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 516
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 645
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Thanks. In Windows, I had to run cmd as Administrator (Start > type cmd > right-click cmd.exe > Run as Administrator). Without doing that, I was getting an error trying to log in to Oracle DB.

Answer (score 28):

From [this](http://daust.blogspot.com/2006/01/xe-changing-default-http-port.html) blog post:

> **XE: Changing the default http port**
>
> Oracle XE uses the embedded http listener that comes with the XML DB
>   (XDB) to serve http requests. The default port for HTTP access is
>   8080.

**EDIT:**

Update 8080 port to which port(9090 for example) you like

```
SQL> -- set http port
SQL> begin
 2    dbms_xdb.sethttpport('9090');
 3  end;
 4  /
```

After changing the port, when we start Oracle it will go on port 8080, we should type manually new port(9090) in the address bar to run Oracle XE.

Comment: getting this error `*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31024: Parser initialization failed with LPX-54 error
while parsing a stream to XOB
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 516
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 645
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Comment: Where do I run this code after logging in Oracle database 11g application express?

Answer (score 12):

Just open `Run SQL Command Line` and login as sysadmin and then enter below command

```
Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(8181);
```

That's it. You are done.....

Comment: getting this error `*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31024: Parser initialization failed with LPX-54 error
while parsing a stream to XOB
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 516
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 645
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Answer (score 9):

Execute `Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(8181);` as SYS/SYSTEM. Replace 8181 with the port you'd like changing to. Tested this with Oracle 10g.

Source : http://hodentekhelp.blogspot.com/2008/08/my-oracle-10g-xe-is-on-port-8080-can-i.html

Comment: getting this error `*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31024: Parser initialization failed with LPX-54 error
while parsing a stream to XOB
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 516
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 645
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Comment: Where do I run this code after logging in Oracle database 11g application express?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're talking about the Apache server that Oracle installs.  Look for the file httpd.conf.

Open this file in a text editor and look for the line
Listen 8080
or
Listen {ip address}:8080

Change the port number and either restart the web server or just reboot the machine.

Comment: what is location of this file ?

Comment: It's been a long time since I dealt with this.  I would run a file search.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle (database) can use many ports.
when you install the software it scans for free ports and decides which port to use then.

The database listener defaults to 1520 but will use 1521 or 1522 if 1520 is not available.
This can be adjusted in the listener.ora files.

The Enterprise Manager, web-based database administration tool defaults to port 80 but will use 8080 if 80 is not available.

See here for details on how to change the port number for enterprise manager:
http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/integrate.1012/b19370/manage_oem.htm#i1012853

Comment: Where do I run this code after logging in Oracle database 11g application express?

Answer (score 1):

There are many Oracle components that run a web service, so it's not clear which you are referring to.

For example, the web site port for standalone OC4J is configured in the j2ee/home/config/default-web-site.xml file:

```
<web-site xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/web-site-10_0.xsd"
port="8888" display-name="OC4J 10g (10.1.3) Default Web Site"
schema-major-version="10" schema-minor-version="0" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Login in with System Admin User Account and execute below SQL Procedure.

```
begin
dbms_xdb.sethttpport('Your Port Number');
end;
```

Then open the Browser and access the below URL

http://127.0.0.1:YourPortNumber/apex/

Comment: Where do I run this code after logging in Oracle database 11g application express?

Comment: In the SQL Editor