# "Access denied" while setting DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPORT

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I was logged in as a normal user into the database:

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: myusername
Enter passwort: 
Connected.
```

And then I tried to set the default http port like this:

```
SQL> Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(3000);
```

But I got the following error message:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31050: Access denied
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 528
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 667
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

What was going wrong? Perhaps because i am not an admin user? But how to add an admin user?

Comment: for you ref :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142868/change-oracle-port-from-port-8080][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142868/change-oracle-port-from-port-8080

Comment: Hello @sukhi, thank you, but my problem is that I am using the same commands but I got "Access denied". Maybe I should add an admin user, but I don't know how.

Comment: Yeah! it appears you missed to add yourself to the sysadmin role when installing SQL Server. If you are a local administrator on your machine,find this link:                                                     
http://blogs.ameriteach.com/chris-randall/2009/12/11/sql-server-2008-forgot-to-add-an-administrator-account.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(3000);
BEGIN dbms_xdb.sethttpport(3000); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31050: Access denied
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 528
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 667
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(3000);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> grant execute on dbms_xdb to hr
  2  /

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(3002);
BEGIN dbms_xdb.sethttpport(3002); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31050: Access denied
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 528
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 667
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant sysdba to hr
  2  /

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn hr/hr as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(3003);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

So you must have the SYSDBA privilege to execute this package.

Comment: Hi, yes it is! I tried "connect username/password@XE as sysdba" and it tells me: insufficient privileges. Do you know how to give myself admin privilege? Thanks!

Comment: @Manuela If you read my answer carefully you would've seen this line: `SQL> grant sysdba to hr` this is how I give to the HR user the `SYSDBA` privilege.