# How to change oracle 10g port 8080 to other port

Tags: oracle

I am trying this method to change my ORACLE XE 10g port 8080 to other port but it shows me this error mentioned below.

As Oracle is using this port due to which I am not able to start my Tomcat on port number 8080.

```
SQL> Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(8181); BEGIN DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(8181); END;

ERROR at line 1: ORA-31050: Access denied ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 382 ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 521 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you `exec` plus have a PLSQL block - usually what you need to do is this:

```
SQL> begin
 2    dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8181');
 3  end;
 4  /
```

And you have to connect as `SYSTEM` - maybe that's why it's denied for you.

Comment: Geziefer I followed your instructions but nothing has happened.

Now I am getting the error as ..

SQL> begin
  2  dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8181');
  3  end;
  4  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31050: Access denied
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 382
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 521
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: @NeerajYadav: I'm pretty sure, you are not connected as SYSTEM, but with some other DB user. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241113/access-denied-while-setting-dbms-xdb-sethttport)

Comment: You were right I was not connected to the system. 
Thanks :) It works @Geziefer

Comment: @NeerajYadav: Since you are new to SO, I add the hint, that if the question was correctly answered and helped you, you should consider voting it up and/or accepting the answer.