# Change port for Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have installed oracle db locally. As result of this I have following application on port `8080` [image]

I've tried to change port with following command:

```
 exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport('9090');
```

As result of this port was changed and following query returns result below:

```
SQL> SELECT dbms_xdb.gethttpport FROM dual;

GETHTTPPORT
-----------
       9090
```

**Edited**

After that I've reloaded PC, but it looks like app is still on the same port. Actually I can see same application on port **8080** and I can see additional thing on port **9090**. Please see image below:

[image]

Could you please advice how to change APEX port?

Comment: how do you mean, still? if you pull up the machine on port 9090 in your browser, do you get the APEX pages? or only if you pull up on port 8080?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I've just added additional details. Could you please take a look into details?

Comment: much more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142868/change-oracle-port-from-port-8080

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thank you, I've looked into the post before I posted this one. I didn't see any additional things there that should be done in order to change port. Could you please point me to some specific thing?

Comment: you say you 'see it' - how? You open the url on port 8080, and it works? If yes, i'd start looking at processes/sessions running to go kill

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yes, I go to localhost:8080 and can see APEX login screen. As I mentioned above, I've tried to restart PC, but there is no luck. Even if I determine the appropriate process I would need to do the same each time when db is restarted.

Comment: Are you running an Oracle REST Data Services setup on port 8080 that is configured to point to your APEX instance?  If so that would explain why you can pull up APEX on port 8080 even though the embedded http server (DBMS_XDB) reports port 9090.  Are you  able to access APEX from both port 8080 and 9090 or just 8080?