# Vaadin with using Jetty Server -> ERROR: Jetty server existing

Tags: jetty, vaadin

I recently started studying Vaadin. At the beginning I am using Vaadin 8 and have started a small Vaadin project in eclipse for practice purposes. I always started and opened this project via Jetty on my localhost:8080. That worked great for the first few days, but since yesterday
my localhost:8080 wants username and password at once and the application is no longer opening there.
The only difference is that the day before yesterday I installed an Oracle database (OracleXE 11 g) - could that have something to do with it?

Here is a snipppet if the error-message that I am getting:

```
Sep. 12, 2021 10:51:20 VORM. org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addInterceptorToAllWrappers
INFORMATION: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@60b616c8{/,file:///C:/Repositories/ProgrammingCourses/Vaadin-and-Maven_Crash-Course/VaadinFirstSteps/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Repositories/ProgrammingCourses/Vaadin-and-Maven_Crash-Course/VaadinFirstSteps/src/main/webapp/}
[INFO] Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  42.520 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-12T10:51:20+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.9.v20160517:run (default-cli) on project VaadinFirstSteps: Failure: Address already in use: bind -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Anyone know how to get Vaadin up and running again? I am grateful fur any help,
Zrebna :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve the "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM\_Bind" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind)

Comment: `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.9.v20160517` - know that Jetty 9.3.x series is EOL (End of Life) - you should upgrade to the `9.4.x` series at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Failure: Address already in use: bind" means that you are trying to start web application server on localhost port 8080 while there is already web application server running and owning that port. Hence new one cannot be started.

You need to check you processes already running and kill the old one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed this was the case - basically the newly installed oracle database has used the port 8080 that is used normally by eclipse for the jetty server...
I just needed to change the port from Oracle DB to another port and did so with the help of this older thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142868/change-oracle-port-from-port-8080/11839354#11839354

This has solved my issue - thanks a lot :)